# Update custom object records from REST api class exposed through site

Tags: apex, rest-api

My goal is simple: call a REST api in salesforce from another platforms webhook and update data in salesforce.

1. For this I am trying to update a custom object record using REST api class that has been exposed via site. But As far I know the site guest users profile can't have Update / Delete permission for objects. Is my understanding correct? setting Rest class as without sharing is an option but not good from security review point of view.
2. Using connected app adds the authentication process and webhook doesn't have customization option where it can first get access token and then use it to make actual webhook API call. So I'm not going for this option.

Is my understanding correct for above 2 options? Thanks for any suggestions